# Javascript Axios get with conditional params

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I am trying to get some data from an API.  The problem is that the GET call could take none or some of the filters.  I have tried but am not sure how/if I can create a URL with conditional filters.

```
actions: {
        InstitutionSearch(value, id){
let fips = id['ParamValues'].find(o=>o.param==='fips')['value'];
            let region = id['ParamValues'].find(o=>o.param==='region')['value'];
axios.get('https://educationdata.urban.org/api/v1/college-university/ipeds/directory/2019/',{
                params:{
                     fips: ,
                     region: region,
                     offering_highest_level: 3
                }
})
};
}
```

This is a vue application, with the code above running inside a vuex store.  The id that is being passed in is an array of objects, that is taken from a search filter form.  The problem that I have is that my query could include either fips or region or none.

My initial thought was the put fips and region equal to 0, but that does not work with my API.  I am not opposed to building a query string inside conditionals, but there has to be an easier way.  The following is an actual query for the data that I am working with https://educationdata.urban.org/api/v1/college-university/ipeds/directory/2019/?offering_highest_level=3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some amazing help, I figured out a simple solution.  I created an empty object and then ran a conditional check on my parameters and only added them, if they met my qualifications.  I then passed that object in as the parameters, and everything worked.

```
let fips = id['ParamValues'].find(o=>o.param==='fips')['value'];
            let region = id['ParamValues'].find(o=>o.param==='region')['value'];
//code change
            let params = {};

            fips.length > 0 ? params['fips'] = fips.join(',') : null;
            region != 0 ? params['region'] = region : null;
//code change
            axios.get('https://educationdata.urban.org/api/v1/college-university/ipeds/directory/2019/',{
                params
            }).then(response=>{
                console.log(response.data.results);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        `http://stream-restaurant-menu-svc.herokuapp.com/item?category=${props.data}`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("This is to show sub-categoary " + response.data);
        setSubcate(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },[props]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).